# Removing the file extension from an outputted name of file in php

Tags: php, directory, echo

I am outputting a directory of files into a drop down list using php.

The file name and extension are both outputted in the list but I would like to only have the file name outputted.

I am using 'basename' before choosing the file but it still outputs the file extension.

here is my code so far

**basename.php**

```
  <?php 
       foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/policies/one/*') as $filename){
       $filename = basename($filename);
       echo "<option value='policies/one/" . $filename . "'>".$filename."</option>";
    }
?>
```

Hope someone can help

cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be used for any type of file extension.

```
<?php 
   foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/policies/one/*') as $filename){
   $filename = basename($filename);
   $filename2 = substr($filename,0,strrpos($filename,".")); //To store the filename upto the last dot(.)
   echo "<option value='policies/one/" . $filename . "'>".$filename2."</option>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This does remove the extension but then when I click on the file to open it, it doesnt because it no longer has its extension

Comment: i have made the appropriate changes

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
  <?php 
       foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/policies/one/*') as $filename){
       $filename2 = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
       echo "<option value='policies/one/" . $filename . "'>".$filename2."</option>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: This does remove the extension but then when I click on the file to open it, it doesnt because it no longer has its extension

Comment: It is normal : you get rid of the extension, so the file path will not be complete.

Comment: Yeah I understand why it has happened, but then what is the point in populating a list with file names that cannot be accessed

Comment: I edited my answer so that the extension of the file is not printed, but the extension is kept inside the `option`. That will fix your second problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
foreach(glob(dirname(__FILE__) . '/policies/one/*') as $filename){
    $filename1 = basename($filename);
    $filename=str_replace(".php","",$filename1)
    echo "<option value='policies/one/" . $filename1 . "'>".$filename."</option>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This does remove the extension but then when I click on the file to open it, it doesnt because it no longer has its extension

Comment: If you remove extension. How it will open @oggle0901?

Comment: Obviously I understand that but then what is the point in populating a list with file names that cant be accessed

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the extension to remove it in advance.

Example from PHP manual

```
$path = "/home/httpd/html/index.php";
$file = basename($path);         // $file is set to "index.php"
$file = basename($path, ".php"); // $file is set to "index"
```